# The row grid displaying the borders

Tags: react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap to displaying grid layout. However both row and col displaying grids and borders. No one of css functions work. What is the reason of that?

[image: This is how it looks]
Here it is my react page.

```
  return (
    <Container fluid>
      <Row>
        <div className="image-container">
          <img src={gameDetails.background_image} class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <ListGroup>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <span
                style={{
                  fontFamily: "Staatliches",
                  fontSize: "20px",
                }}
              >
                Name:
              </span>{" "}
              {gameDetails.name}
            </ListGroup.Item>
          </ListGroup>
        </Col>
        <ListGroup>
          <ListGroup.Item>
            <span
              style={{
                fontFamily: "Staatliches",
                fontSize: "20px",
              }}
            >
              Release Date:
            </span>{" "}
            {gameDetails.released}
          </ListGroup.Item>
        </ListGroup>
        <Col></Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default GameDesc;
```

I have tried to use CSS functions such as `border: no` but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The border styling applies to the `<ListGroup.Item>` element. Add `border: "none"` to that.

Comment: I tried using `border:none` but still seeing same results.